# Create loop animation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a loop animation with Jquery and an external library, but I have some problems with setinterval and loop.

```
  var p = ['Forex', 'Commodities', 'Index', 'Crypto']
var i = 0;
function eachChange(i) {

    $('.title').each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(p[i])
        var el = $(this);
        el.find('.text').html(p[i])

        el.find('.bar').animate({width:'70%'},600,$.myeas([0.7, 0, 0.175, 1]));
        setTimeout(function(){
            el.find('.text').animate({width:'100%'},600,$.myeas([0.7, 0, 0.175, 1]));

            setTimeout(function () {
                el.find('.text').delay(5000).animate({width: '0',}, 600, $.myeas([0.7, 0, 0.175, 1]));

                if( i <= p.length-1) {
                    console.log( i)
                    i++;
                    eachChange(i);
                }else{
                    console.log("restart")
                    eachChange(0);
                }

            }, 300)



        },5000 * (index + 1))


    });
}
```

Here my Javascript: https://codepen.io/plancton0618/pen/oNLBzga
My problem is the timeout and the restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something every 5 seconds, begin with setInterval and do everything that needs to be done in the callback function.  If you do that, you won't need nested setTimeout functions, which should bring the complexity way down.

To keep looping through your array of words, you don't need to reset i to 0.  You can just always use i % p.length as the index and continue to iterate i forever.